# Problem finding metafonts at compilation

Tags: fonts, compiling, metafont

I'm trying to compile a document using the `latex` command.  This document compiles fine on other machines, but on the machine I'm currently using (Ubuntu 12.04 with texlive installed via aptitude), it doesn't work.

Here's a portion of the compile log that seems relevant to me:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm rsfs10
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs10
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf rsfs10
! I can't find file `rsfs10'.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs10

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs10

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: rsfs10.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs10' failed to make rsfs10.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font U/rsfs/m/n/8=rsfs10 at 8.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.71 

?
```

Frankly, I have no idea what's wrong here.  I should note that I'm using the following document class:

```
(./svjour3.cls
Document Class: svjour3 2007/05/08 v3.2 
LaTeX document class for Springer journals
(./svglov3.clo
SVJour Class option: svglov3.clo for standardised journals
))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried to compile another document (one that doesn't use the svjour3 doc class) using `pdflatex`, and I got a similar error: `Font OT1/ptm/m/n/10.95=ptmr7t at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not 
found.`

Comment: There are tfm-files missing. So quite probably you simply don't have the fonts installed. Check if there are some more tex packages you can install. (With a current TeXLive you need to install with tlmgr times + rsfs.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks.  Following your advice, I installed the following Ubuntu packages: `texlive-fonts-extra`, `texlive-fonts-extra-doc`, `texlive-fonts-recommended`, `texlive-fonts-recommended-doc`, and `tipa`.  This fixed the problem.

Comment: I could be thanking you @synaptik for another 3 hours, the time I spent searching a solution so simple as installing fonts.

Comment: This is the case when I installed BasicTex on my (small hard drive capacity) Mac and had trouble compiling my thesis. sudo tlmgr install rsfs did the trick thanks @UlrikeFischer

Comment: sudo apt-get install texlive-full
solved my problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are `tfm`-files missing. So quite probably you simply don't have the fonts installed. Check if there are some more tex packages you can install. (With a current TeXLive you need to install with `tlmgr times` + `rsfs`.) –

Answer (score 9):

`sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended`

After installing the recommended fonts the compliation worked like a charm.

Comment: For me it was `texlive-fonts-extra` (620MB!).

Answer (score 8):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60703643/11155167), the following works too:

```
sudo tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/203646)

Comment: @naphaneal There is nothing in the link that is not in this answer; this answer is complete in itself.

Comment: This includes rsf!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on mac os because I choose to install only the basic livetex 2013 package.

So the rsfs package was missing.

I solved this by installing the https://code.google.com/p/mactlmgr/ TeX Live Utility.

This is a small tool that allow to download and install automatically whatever package is missing from the tex live repository.

After installing the package refs everything works perfectly