# Why are tfm files missing in the LaTeX rsfs package?

Tags: fonts, metafont

I try to solve my problem asked on stackoverflow about a python script which uses TeX to create matplotlib labels. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50875637/matplotlib-how-do-i-have-to-provide-font-metrics-files-for-rendering-text-by-te for details.

It turns out that a tfm file is missing.
FileNotFoundError: missing font metrics file: rsfs10

However, the package rsfs is installed, but the package does not contain the tfm files. https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/rsfs/
Is there any reason for that? Where could I get such tfm file?

I already found a similar topic: [Problem finding metafonts at compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97123/problem-finding-metafonts-at-compilation) 
The solution which was provided there, was the installation of the package. But this is already done on my system.

Comment: the ctan package has the metafont sources so the tfm  would be generated from them by metafont  but you should have the tfm  in texlive or miktex in a location such as `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/rsfs/rsfs10.tfm`

Comment: how did you install the rsfs package? using your package installer, or by hand fetching the files from ctan?

Comment: I used the MikTeX 2.9 package installer. How do I have to generate the tfm files from the source?

Comment: on the comandline `mf rsfs10` should do it but if the miktex package installer didn't install the tfm then that is a bug you should report (I don't have miktex to test)

Comment: I don't know about miktex but on texlive if you just try to tex a document using the fonts it will run metafont for you and make the tfm for a font that has the mf files installed but not the tfm

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have done mf rsfs10 on the command line. a new file rsfs10.2602gf is generated, but it is not the tfm file. What do I do with that?

Comment: you can throw that one away (in general it can be converted to a pk font file but you don't need that) but it should have made a tfm at the same time no that's wrong (I just tried:-) it's so long since I did that by hand I forget will answer later if no one else does

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In my case it creates this rsfs10.2602gf and a log rsfs10.log. No error message inside the log file.

Comment: sorry try `mktextfm rsfs10` which works for me it's a wrapper script that passes the right options to mf to make a tfm

Comment: the tfm is not in the package but with my miktex it is created automatically from the sources at the first use of the font.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of the discussion of my question (see comments), I found a solution:

On my computer, the MikTex installation was quite new, and the font has never been used before, therefore the required tfm files had not been created.

However, the matplotlib Python package (dviread.py) tried to identify the tfm files before usage in order to create a fontfile cache (see question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50875637/matplotlib-how-do-i-have-to-provide-font-metrics-files-for-rendering-text-by-te)

I have installed a complete TeXLive installation on another computer. There the tfm files were already created during installation and I just copied the files to the corresponding location on my computer.

Answer (score 3):

While the answer and comments by Stellarator and David Carlisle were helpful, the commands did not work (specifically the `mktextfm rsfs10` suggestion in the comments). I also preferred not to reinstall the Miktex in its entirety since I already spent some time getting everything set up and running with other external programs.

I did a little searching within the C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64 folder and it looks like running:

```
miktex-maketfm.exe rsfs10
```

did the trick. It built rsfs10.tfm and put it within the C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\fonts\tfm\public\rsfs folder.

It's possible the authors of Miktex renamed the wrapper script that David Carlisle mentioned. This problem surfaced for me when I wanted to use tex rendering within `matplotlib` with the `times` font family. The error it was giving me in the python console was:

```
FileNotFoundError: missing font metrics file: rsfs10
```

Note that this solution is for Miktex 20.10. Once I ran this, matplotlib had no problems.

Comment: Welcome to this site! Thanks for sharing what worked for you; it looks like it might be useful to others as well.

Comment: (+1) in case MiKTeX is installed for a single user and not for all users, the `miktex-maketfm.exe` binary can be found in the directory `C:\Users\<username here>\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64` instead.